# matplotlib setting axis limits is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, contextily

I am trying to specify figure limits in matplotlib, but they are not being enforced. I am setting the limits in my subplot, and I saw the figures were clearly at different extents, so I have printed out the specified and actual limits to confirm that they are different.

How can I force the figure limits, regardless of data extents?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily as ctx

def mymap(df, xlimits, ylimits):
    mycolorsdict = {'A':'green', 'B':'orange', 'C':'blue'}
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
    
    for key, group in df.groupby('category'):
        group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', 
                   x='long', y='lat', 
                   color=mycolorsdict[key]
                  )
    ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs='epsg:4326', 
                    source=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldShadedRelief
                   )
    ax.set_xlim = xlimits
    ax.set_ylim = ylimits
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=8)
    print(ylimits, ax.get_ylim())
    print(xlimits, ax.get_xlim())
```

And when I run this function for a couple of dataframes, the maps are *not* at the same limits nor at the limits I specified.

```
xl = [-116.423639, -116.120922]
yl = [34.288848, 34.779539]

for cat in df.category.unique():
        df2 = df[df.category == cat].copy()
        mymap(df2, xl, yl)
```

It returns limits different that what I specified. What I specified is on the left, and the actual are on the right.

```
[34.288848, 34.779539] (34.26499695, 34.80380005000001)
[-116.423639, -116.120922] (-116.43791284999999, -116.10754215000003)
[34.288848, 34.779539] (34.327880050000005, 34.71235095)
[-116.423639, -116.120922] (-116.38095349999999, -116.1129605)
```

Comment: Without trying. I'd guess it's because you enforce an equal aspect ratio after setting the limitd

Comment: it makes no difference if it is before, and the specified limits are the same for both plots, so it should be making the exact same adjustment for both plots

Comment: replacing `ax.set_xlim = xlimits` in the function with `plt.xlim([xlimits[0], xlimits[1]])` etc. seems to fix this.

Comment: `ax.set_xlim` is a method, so you must call it `ax.set_xlim(xlimits)`.

Comment: @JodyKlymak that is super helpful, thank you. I upvoted it here, but if you write it as an answer I will also accept it